# Copy data in array of a nested array of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy, arrayobject, nested-object

So guys, I don't how to give a topic to this one. I'm having trouble to copy data from array of Object to another newly created array.

**For example**, I want to copy and create a new `array` that contain all category of animals of every person in my database.

```
 people = [ 
     {
         name: "Person 1",
         animals: [
             { category: "cat" },
             { category: "dog" },
             { category: "fish" }
         ]
     },
     {
         name: "Person 2",
         animals: [
             { category: "dog" },
             { category: "iguana" }
         ]
     },
     {
         name: "Person 3",
         animals: [
             { category: "cat" }
         ]
     }
 ]
```

So, I created a new `array` named `animalCategory` to hold every category available.

```
 // declare new array to hold category of animals
 let animalCategory = []
```

This is the logic I came up with:-

```
// loop all person available
people.forEach(person => {
    // go and loop inside animals array
    person.animals.forEach(animal => {
        // save new category of animals if animalCategory array is EMPTY
        if(animalCategory.length === 0) {
            animalCategory.push(animal.category)
        }

        // if NOT EMPTY, then
        else {
            // loop and check existing animal categories in animalCategory array
            animalCategory.forEach(category => {
                // check if MATCH?
                if(category === animal.category) {
                    break // or just continue or will NOT BE SAVE
                }

                // if NOT MATCH, then
                else {
                    // SAVE new category
                    animalCategory.push(animal.category)
                }
            })
        }
    })
})

// see result
console.log(animalCategory.length)
```

But unfortunately I got like a very big array of `animalCategory` as a result. And a lot of **repetative** animals category. *(like shown below)*

[image]

**UPDATED**: the output I want to seek is:-

```
animalCategory: [ 'cat', 'dog', 'iguana', 'fish']
```

How should I change my **logic** then? And is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: I'm having a hard time identifying what data you have to start with an what data you want as output. If `people` as defined in your first codeblock is your input, can you include a codeblock with your expected output?

Comment: @Chase Already updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: Is the issue the duplicate values? Or is there more?

Comment: @Chase Yes. How can I get rid of the duplicate values? That's the only thing I'm having trouble with

Comment: Got it. Added an answer that takes care of that and simplifies the array construction quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
people = [ 
     {
         name: "Person 1",
         animals: [
             { category: "cat" },
             { category: "dog" },
             { category: "fish" }
         ]
     },
     {
         name: "Person 2",
         animals: [
             { category: "dog" },
             { category: "iguana" }
         ]
     },
     {
         name: "Person 3",
         animals: [
             { category: "cat" }
         ]
     }
 ]

// declare new array to hold category of animals
 let animalCategory = []


// loop all person available
people.forEach(person => {
    // go and loop inside animals array
    person.animals.forEach(animal => {
        // save new category of animals if animalCategory array is EMPTY
        if(animalCategory.length === 0) {
            animalCategory.push(animal.category)
        }

        // if NOT EMPTY, then
        else {
            if(animalCategory.indexOf(animal.category) === -1) {
            
            animalCategory.push(animal.category);
            }
        }
    });
});

// see result
animalCategory.forEach(function(animal) {
    console.log(animal);
});
```

Hope this is helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that gets the output you're looking for with duplicates removed.

```js
people = [ 
     {
         name: "Person 1",
         animals: [
             { category: "cat" },
             { category: "dog" },
             { category: "fish" }
         ]
     },
     {
         name: "Person 2",
         animals: [
             { category: "dog" },
             { category: "iguana" }
         ]
     },
     {
         name: "Person 3",
         animals: [
             { category: "cat" }
         ]
     }
 ];
 
 const uniqAnimals = [...new Set(people.flatMap(p => p.animals).map(a => a.category))];
 
 console.log(uniqAnimals);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Set are made up of only unique values.

It wont matter if you push the same value it just won't add it to the set.

If you want to then convert the categories back to an array use the [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) Method and pass in the set.

```
let animalCategory = new Set()
people.forEach(person => {
    // go and loop inside animals array
    person.animals.forEach(animal => {
          animalCategory.add(animal.category)
    })
})
animalCategory = Array.from(animalCategory)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's another solution.

```
people.forEach(people => {
   if (people.animals && people.animals.length) {
       people.animals.forEach(categories => {
           if (animalCategories.indexOf(categories.category) === -1) {
               animalCategories.push(categories.category);
           }
       });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can collect all category property values in array and from it we would remove duplicates values.

```
var people = [{
    name: "Person 1",
    animals: [{
        category: "cat"
      },
      {
        category: "dog"
      },
      {
        category: "fish"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Person 2",
    animals: [{
        category: "dog"
      },
      {
        category: "iguana"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Person 3",
    animals: [{
      category: "cat"
    }]
  }
];
var getArr = [];
var animalsArr = people.map(x => x.animals.map(y => {
  getArr.push(y.category);
}));

var filteredArr = getArr.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
console.log(filteredArr);
```